# Make an almost "head" coin into a fair coin

Tags: probability, expected-value, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The question is suppose we have a biased coin which lands head with probability $p = 0.99$. How can we find an efficient way to turn that into a fair coin (with less than 100 expected flips).

So in this type of question, the usual way when $p$ is not too different than 0.5 is to implement Von Neumann's Unfair Coin Solution. For example, we flip twice and assign "Head Tail" to Head and "Tail Head" to Tail.

However, as now the coin almost lands head and it will take a lot flips to stop the simulation. I am wondering if there is any algorithm that can improve the efficiency?

Comment: Maybe you can use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution and calculate the mean and standard deviation for n flips. If you arrive at greater than the mean value by the nth flip, consider this a 'heads' outcome, and less than, 'tails'. They each have approximately 0.5 probability depending on n

Comment: For this coin, the expected number of flips in Von Neumann's method is $99,$ which is less than $100.$ I suppose you really wanted *much less* than $100$ flips.

Comment: Von Neumann's method should be 1/(0.99*0.01) expected flips?

Answer (score 4):

$(0.99)^n = 0.5\\
n\log(0.99) = \log 0.5\\
n = \frac {\log(0.5)}{\log(0.99)} \approx 69$

If you flip this coin 69 times with probability $0.4998$ you will see all heads.  I can't see a way to do this with fewer than 69 flips.